# PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoScreenshot for iOS8

Tags: ios, ios9, photosframework, phasset

The title makes it self explanatory I think

Since ALAssets library is deprecated I'm trying to convert everything over from a project I started on a while back. Photos framework has a typedef enum for [PHAssetMediaSubtype](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/PHAssetMediaSubtype) and it makes it easy to identify which photos were taken as a screen shot with a device : `PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoScreenshot`. However, the worst caveat to that feature is, out of all the constants listed in that enum, that particular instance is the *only* one not compatible with iOS8.

Long story short - can someone lead me in the direction to finding the value of metadata or dict info for a picture that identifies it as a screenshot? Preferably keeping with the photos framework or something already implemented that doesn't call for additional frameworks or imports. FYI, not looking for 3rd party options as an answer. Keep it in house please, I'm positive I'm overlooking something simple

Comment: Hey, did you ever find a solution? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Hey @soulshined, what I ended up doing was using the pixelWidth and pixelHeight properties and seeing if they matched up to the screen resolution. Not an ideal implementation, but nevertheless I think it accounts for most of the cases that we're trying to find. See https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/PHAsset/pixelWidth